# 3 divs covering whole window

Tags: html, css

I have little problem with positioning divs with CSS - I would like to make 3 divs that cover whole window:

- div1 (top) with width 100% and constant height
- div2 (left-bottom) with constant width and full height
- div3 (right-bottom) with the remaining width, also full height

Is there any way to do this without JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5V48p/1/

**EDIT - Just saw your comment about fluid height for bottom divs - see this: http://jsfiddle.net/5V48p/2/**

THE HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="top">Word, yo.</div>
    <div id="bottom-left">Look at me!</div>
    <div id="bottom-right">Hobajoba!</div>
</body>
```

THE CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#top {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#bottom-left {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
    margin-top:100px;
}
#bottom-right {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width: calc(100% - 180px);
    margin-left:180px;
    background-color: pink;
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, css "calc" function - that's what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
.div1 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 100px;
}
.div2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
.div3 {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vfBL2/)

Comment: Thanks, but div2 and div3 can't have a constant height.

Answer (score 0):

Here, checkout my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shwunky/nwy6h/

Basically, it's a play on `z-index`

The only problem I see with this one is that if you remove the bottom right and top divisions, the bottom left division would fill the whole viewport.

Comment: Ok, but if I'll put something in a "botright" div, it will be covered by other divs.

Comment: If for example you put a paragraph into the botright div, you could make it have relative positioning and offset its top by the height of the top div and offset its left by the width of the bottom left div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with javascript.  The key is to understand how to take advantage of position: absolute.

Here's a JS Fiddle showing you how it can be done:
http://jsfiddle.net/cbbZq/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div id="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `table,tr,td` as follows:

```
<body>
    <table class="table" cellspacing="0">
        <tr id="top">
            <td  colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="division">
            <td id="left"></td>
            <td id="right"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

and css:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
.table {
    height: 100%;
}
#division {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#left {
    background-color:green;
    min-width: 100px;
}

#right {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aneelkkhatri/2c7ag/1/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="top">TOP AREA</div>
    <div id="bottom-right">
          <div id="bottom-left">
               FIXED WIDTH
          </div>
          NOT FIXED
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;}

#top
{
  width:100%;
}

#bottom-left
{
  width:180px;
  float:left;
}

#bottom-right
{
  width:100%;
}
```